# C/C++ private array initialization in the header file

Tags: c++, arrays, header, initialization

I have a class called Cal and it's .cpp and .h counterpart

Headerfile has

```
class Cal {
    private:
        int wa[2][2];

    public:
        void do_cal();
};
```

.cpp file has

```
#include "Cal.h"
void Cal::do_cal() {
   print(wa) // where print just itterates and prints the elements in wa
}
```

My question is how do I initialize the array `wa` ? I just can't seem to get it to work.

I tried with :

```
int wa[2][2] = {
                {5,2},
                {7,9}
               };
```

in the header file but I get errors saying I cant do so as it's against iso..something.

Tried also to initialize the array `wa` in the constructor but that didnt work either.. What am I missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it can be static, you can initialize it in your .cpp file. Add the static keyword in the class declaration:

```
class Cal {
    private:
        static int wa[2][2];
    public:
        void do_cal();
};
```

and at file scope in the .cpp file add:

```
#include "Cal.h"
int Cal::wa[2][2] = { {5,2}, {7,9} };
void Cal::do_cal() {
   print(wa) // where print just itterates and prints the elements in wa
}
```

If you never change it, this would work well (along with making it const). You only get one that's shared with each instance of your class though.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot initialize array elements in a class declaration. I recently tried to find a way to do just that. From what I learned, you have to do it in your initialize function, one element at a time.

```
Cal::Cal{
   wa[0][0] = 5;
   wa[0][1] = 2;
   wa[1][0] = 7;
   wa[1][1] = 9;
}
```

It's possible (and probable) that there's a much better way to do this, but from my research last week, this is how to do it with a multi dimensional array.
I'm interested if anyone has a better method.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it easily.  If you don't want to specify each element individually like in [Perchik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520893/c-c-private-array-initialization-in-the-header-file/520917#520917), you can create one static array and `memcpy` that (which will probably be faster for non-trivial array sizes):

```
namespace
{
    const int default_wa[2][2] = {{5, 2}, {7, 9}};
}

Cal::Cal
{
    memcpy(&wa[0][0], &default_wa[0][0], sizeof(wa));
}
```

Comment: memcpy is dangerous here. If someone in the future changes the dimensions or type of one array without reflecting those changes in the other...

Comment: True, but you'd have the same problem with any other solution.  You could easily throw in an assert(sizeof(wa) == sizeof(default_wa)) here to protect against that in this case.

Comment: You can make sure that the array sizes always match if you define them like this: `int default_wa[][2] = {{ 5, 2 }, { 7, 9 }}; int wa[count(default_wa)][count(default_wa[0])];` with `#define count(ARRAY) ((sizeof (ARRAY))/(sizeof (ARRAY[0])))`

Comment: Good point Christoph, I've done that before. I hate #defining count() every time I need it - should have been a built-in feature.

Comment: Should also point out that you can use a static within the constructor, rather than putting the defaults in a namespace outside. But only if you don't need an inline constructor. It enhances the readability.