# C++ - Initialize private array in c++ class

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm having a problem of storing data into the private array in a class.

I tried to Google and didn't find any solution.

Here's my code:

Foo.h

```
class Foo {
private:
    int arr[10];
    double d;
public:
    Foo::Foo(double d) {
        this->d = d;
    }
    // ...
};
```

Foo.cpp

```
int main() {
    double d = 123.456;
    int array[10];
    // Getting data from user input by for-loop 10 times.

    Foo f = Foo(d);
```

And here's my problem -- how to save the *array* into the *f*?

Seems like using pointer (`*f.arr = array;`) doesn't acturally change the *arr*.

---

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2083002/5343689) by adding

```
class Foo {
// ...
Public:
    Foo::Foo(int arr_, double d_) : arr_(new int[10]), d_(d) { };
```

But the Visual Studio 2017 says the array is not initialized.

---

I also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/521650/5343689), but VS says cannot modify the array in this scope.

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't use arrays, use vectors.

Comment: You should ask for an array of integers in the constructor, not a single integer. And then copy all values into array. Don't use new because Foo::arr is already allocated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <algorithm>  // std::copy()
#include <iterator>   // std::size()

class Foo {
private:
    int arr[10];
    double d;
public:
    Foo(double d, int *data)
    : d{ d }
    {
        std::copy(data, data + std::size(arr), arr);
    }
    // ...
};
```